# Sharing a semaphore with a function using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to synchronise access to a shared resource across multiple workers in a python `multiprocessing.Pool` by passing a semaphore to a function. Here is some pseudocode.

```
def do_work(payload, semaphore):
    with semaphore:
        access_the_shared_resource(payload)
```

The function `do_work` is defined in a library such that I cannot define a semaphore in my local scope that the function can inherit. I can also not pass a semaphore using `functools.partial` because `multiprocessing` attempts to pickle the semaphore which is not allowed. What seems to work is using a `multiprocessing.Manager` to create a proxy to a `Semaphore`:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
semaphore = manager.Semaphore()

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(functools.partial(do_work, semaphore=semaphore), payloads)
```

Is this the best approach or am I missing the obvious solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your only other option is to use `initializer` and `initargs` to pass a regular `multiprocessing.Semaphore` to each worker process at pool creation time, and use it as a global variable:

```
semaphore = None
def do_work(payload):
    with semaphore:
        return payload

def init(sem):
    global semaphore
    semaphore = sem

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sem = multiprocessing.Semaphore()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(sem,)) as p:
        results = p.map(do_work, payloads)
```

The global `semaphore` variable you define in the parent will be set to the `multiprocessing.Semaphore()` in each child process.

Using the `manager.Semaphore()` is fine, though it does require spawning an extra Python process.